# Can .XML file set a value from variable in a .txt or .py?

Tags: python, xml, wix

I have multiple xml files (Actually .wxs for Wix Toolset) that all need to get a programs version that updates regularly. I want all the files to automatically get the latest version number.  The program has a file formed like this:

**Version.py**

```
version='0.4.22'
```

Is it possible to get the variable **version** from **Version.py** into my .xml file?

Maybe something looking like this:

```
<VARIABLE app_version FILE="\\version.py" SELECT="version" />

<Product Name="MyApp" Version=&app_version; />
```

Comment: You mean you want to read Version value ? or you want to set the version value coming from some other files? both are possible.

Comment: Yes I want to read the value  of Version from version.py and how to assign that value to an Element attribute.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question, is that you want the `version` variable's value to be placed inside the .XML file's version attribute inside the Product tag.

You could just open the XML file in the script and automate it to write the updated version number from the Versions.py file to the XML file.

So, every time you run your script, it will update the XML file

Comment: Ah, did not really understand your answer first and I realize my question does not explain everything but Yes this does help. I'm building from a .bat file and from there i can set my variables and should be able to get value from an other file. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you just want read the `version` setting value from a `.py` file and used the setting value in the `.wxml` file.

In `.wxs` just read the `.py` file as a text file and get the `version` setting value, and then assign the setting value to the `.wxml` view.

Comment: Well yes but I cant' figure out how to read a text file and read a specific value.